# preg_match_all で指定した正規表現が意図した通りマッチしない

Tags: php, html, 正規表現

下記のように `href` が `#title` から始まる `<a>` タグを全て削除したいのですが、
現在のコードだと上手く `preg_match_all` が動作していません。
どう変更すればよいでしょうか？

**$content**

```html
<a href="#title1">stack</a>
<a href="#title2">overflow</a>
```

**現在のコード**

```php
if (preg_match_all('|<a href=\"^#title.*$\".*?>(.*?)</a>|mis', $content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
    if (!empty($matches)) {
        $content = preg_replace('|<a href=\"^#title.*$\".*?>(.*?)</a>|mis', '', $content);
    }
}
```

Comment: `'|<a href="#title.*?">(.*?)</a>|mis'` で良いのではないでしょうか。

Comment: @metropolis いけました、ありがとうございます！